# In my VM a application which is linked to databases is not opening where it is opening in other vm?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The application works like it converts one data format file to another these files get store in linked databases,May i know how to resolve this problem through **optimizing sql database**? 
 please help thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I can't show you that application here at stackoverflow . have you got the issue ?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: i have tag as sql-server

Comment: Title is talking about VMs. Body doesn't talk about them at all, then suddenly says "how to resolve this problem" and starts talking about *optimizing* a database. I have literally no clear idea on *what you're trying to ask about*.